# Page still refresh after adding UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, updatepanel

I trying to add UpdatePanel into my web application which allow user to upload image using a FileUpload control. I use this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prathore/fileupload-control-in-update-panel-using-Asp-Net-ajax/) as my reference.
But the UpdatePanel don't seem to work, after file uploaded it keep refreshing the entire page instead of the image portion. Below is my code.

Aspx:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
<ContentTemplate>
<table width="75%" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" class="auto-style1">
            <h2 align="center">My Profile</h2>
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>

  <tr>

        <td id ="memberprofileimage" align="center" class="auto-style2">
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" src="image/defaultProfile.jpg" Width="200" Height="200"/>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnupdatepic" runat="server" Text="Update profile picture " OnClick="btnupdatepic_Click" />
            <br />
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" Visible="false"/>
            <br />
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"   
            ControlToValidate="FileUpload1" Runat="Server" Visible="false" ErrorMessage="Only jpg files are allowed"   
            ValidationExpression="^.+\.((jpg)|(JPG))$"/>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" Visible="false"/>
            <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" Visible="false"/>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblUpload" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

        </td>

        <td id ="memberprofiledetail" align="left" width="50%">
           <b> Full Name 
            <br />
            </b>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFullName" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" Width="270px"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <br />

            <b>Contact </b>&nbsp;<br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtContact" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" Width="160px"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revContact" runat="server"  
    ControlToValidate="txtContact" 
    ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{8}$" 
    ErrorMessage="Please enter your Contact Number."  ForeColor="Red">
    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvContact" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="Please enter your Contact Number." 
    ControlToValidate="txtContact" ForeColor="Red">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />

            <b>Address 
            <br />
            </b>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" Width="300px" Height="40px"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAddress" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="Please enter your Address." 
    ControlToValidate="txtAddress" ForeColor="Red">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />

            <b>Email 
            <br />
            </b>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" Width="270px"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revEmail" runat="server"  
    ControlToValidate="txtEmail" 
    ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" 
    ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid Email."  ForeColor="Red">
    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEmail" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="Please enter your Email." 
    ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ForeColor="Red">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="BtnDisplay" runat="server" Text="Edit profile" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="BtnDisplay_Click" />
            <br />
            <br />       
            <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update Profile" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" Visible="False" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnChangePassword" runat="server" Text="Change Password" OnClick="btnChangePassword_Click" CausesValidation="False" />
        </td>

    </tr>   
</table>   
     </ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID = "btnUpload" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data");

        if (Session["LoginAs"] != "Member")
        {
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            String nric = (String)Session["nric"];

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("Select * from MemberAccount where nric = '" + nric + "'", con);
                SqlDataReader dr;
                dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    txtFullName.Text = dr["fullname"].ToString();
                    txtAddress.Text = dr["address"].ToString();
                    txtContact.Text = dr["contact"].ToString();
                    txtEmail.Text = dr["email"].ToString();
                }

                con.Close();
            }

            Image1.Attributes["src"] = "MemberProfilePicture.aspx?";
            Image1.Attributes["height"] = "200";
            Image1.Attributes["width"] = "200";
        }
    }

protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String nric = (String)Session["nric"];

        string filePath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);

        string contenttype = String.Empty;

        switch (ext)
        {
            case ".jpg":
                contenttype = "image/jpg";
                break;
            case ".JPG":
                contenttype = "image/jpg";
                break;
        }
        if (contenttype != String.Empty)
        {
            System.Drawing.Image uploaded = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream);

            System.Drawing.Image newImage = new Bitmap(1024, 768);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
            {
                g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                g.DrawImage(uploaded, 0, 0, 1024, 768);
            }

            byte[] results;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                ImageCodecInfo codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().FirstOrDefault(c => c.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid);
                EncoderParameters jpegParms = new EncoderParameters(1);
                jpegParms.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 95L);
                newImage.Save(ms, codec, jpegParms);
                results = ms.ToArray();
            }

            //insert the file into database
            string strQuery = "Update MemberAccount Set profilepicture = @Data Where nric = @Nric";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Nric", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nric;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", results);

            InsertUpdateData(cmd);

            lblUpload.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            lblUpload.Text = "Profile Picture Updated.";

            Page_Load(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        else if (contenttype == String.Empty)
        {
            lblUpload.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            lblUpload.Text = "Please select your image before uploading!";
        }
        else
        {
            lblUpload.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            lblUpload.Text = "File format not recognised." + " Upload jpg formats";
        }

        btnCancel.Visible = false;
        FileUpload1.Visible = false;
        btnUpload.Visible = false;
        btnupdatepic.Visible = true;

    }

    private Boolean InsertUpdateData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FileUpload` control will not work with Asynchronous postback and therefore it will not work from within an AJAX `UpdatePanel`.  ***In case you use the  FileUpload control within an UpdatePanel, You will still need a full postback***. `AsyncPostBackTrigger` will not do the trick for a FileUpload control.

***In case you want to upload a file asynchronously***, use: `AsyncFileUpload` control .We can place this within update panel or outside the update panel

```
<cc1:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload1" ... />
```

Check the complete article ***[here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42865/AsyncFileUpload-Control-New-Control-in-Ajax-Contro)*** on AsyncFileUpload control.

So, In short , `FileUpload` control needs a full postback to function.
However, the rest of the controls can still take advantage of the asynchronous postbacks provided by the UpdatePanel.

You need to use the ***[PostBackTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.postbacktrigger.aspx)*** only in any case to make the `FileUpload` control work from Update panel.

```
<Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="myButton" /> 
 </Triggers>
```

**NOTE:** There is NO such property: `EventName` for PostBackTrigger.

***[Read this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16945/Simple-AJAX-File-Upload)*** beautiful article on this concept for more.

Comment: I understand that FileUpload control only work with UpdatePanel with PostBackTrigger. The problem now I facing was the whole page is refreshing after file uploaded, instead of it refreshing the image portion only.

Comment: Yes, Whole page will be refreshed only, Since this will be a normal postback similar to other postback methods like: Button click etc. The <asp:PostbackTrigger>  does this full postback indeed.

Comment: Please see my Edit above. In case you want to upload a file asynchronously, use AsyncFileUpload.

Comment: I change my FileUpload control to AsyncFileUpload control but the problem still remain there.

Comment: This should not be the case. The onuploadedcomplete is a server side event, so it will be called if defined, but whole page should not refresh. Any code lines you suspect to be of issue??

Comment: Am I right to just change my FileUpload control to AsyncFileUpload control? Is it a must to have OnUploadComplete method in AsyncFileUpload Control? I just add a AsyncFileUpload control with ID, runat="Server" and my upload function code still in btnUpload_Click method?

Comment: YES, Change the FileUpload to AsyncFileUpload. Also, OnUploadedComplete is the event that confirms that your file is loaded completely.As soon as you select the file, uploading starts but it remains in session. It is not stored on any physical location. It is recommended to use OnUploadedComplete for saving the file once the loading is fully completed. Also, There is NO need to use btnUpload_Click anymore. I guess this btnUpload_Click is causing full postback only.

Comment: Also, please  change the UpdateMode of your update panel to "Conditional"

Comment: Is there anyway to keep the btnUpload to upload the image but not to cause a full postback after it been uploaded? To me without a upload button will cause problem like, what if i uploaded selected some images wrongly and the control already upload the image incorrectly. To me the btnUpload is for confirmation.

Comment: Unfortunately NO. This is because FileUpload control needs a Full page Postback. This is a Limitation for this control. May be we can expect in future releases to get this upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding [AsyncPostBackTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger.aspx) or the older PostBackTrigger to your UpdatePanel inside Triggers tag like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
<Triggers>

 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload_Click" EventName="Click" />

<!-- OR 
 <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload_Click" />
-->

</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
```

ControlID Gets or sets the name of the control that triggers an asynchronous postback for an UpdatePanel control.

Comment: I get this error after changing to your code: `A control with ID 'btnUpload_Click' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'.`

Comment: as you can see, the `btnUpload_Click` is just an example, you can change it to other button/control from your `UpdatePanel` (eg `btnUpload`) and you can remove the `EventName="Click"`.

Comment: It don't work if I used `<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload" EventName="Click" />`

Comment: As what I google AsyncPostBackTrigger isn't working with FileUpload control.

Comment: Does the PostBackTrigger work? I knew that it has some sort of bug on AsynchPostBack Trigger, but there is work around for that and that's a different issue.

Comment: Yes, it able to upload image just that it still keep freshing the whole page after image uploaded instead of just refreshing the portion of the image uploaded.